# Files vs InputStreams

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm reading a excel file by Poi(3.7). I'm learning somethins about poi at this link [Poi Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream). Now my concerns is about this:

> When opening a workbook, either a .xls HSSFWorkbook, or a .xlsx XSSFWorkbook, the Workbook can be loaded from either a File or an InputStream. Using a File object allows for lower memory consumption, while an InputStream requires more memory as it has to buffer the whole file

In the 3.7 version to Poi the WorkbookFactory doesn't have  following method

> WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"))

and i try to load my file in these ways:

**First way**

```
InputStream  is  = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MyExcel.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
```

**Second way**

```
String path = getClass().getResource("/MyExcel.xlsx").getPath();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
```

Now i want to ask you, what is background difference of these three possibilities to load an excel file? Which of these do you suggest?

Comment: Well if you use FileInputStream, you need a file... if you just use Class.getResourceAsStream, you need a resource on the classpath, but it doesn't have to be on the file system...

Comment: Check class of 'is' and 'fis' and compare their implementation.

Comment: Apache POI 3.7 is pretty old - is there a reason why you haven't upgraded to a newer one? (eg 3.10 which does support the lower memory loading from files)

Answer (score 0):

First way is good if your file is located in file system. Second way is actually wrong. If your file is a part of your application, i.e. avaliable from the classpath use the following code:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MyExcel.xlsx").getPath());
```

What's wrong with your code? Actually it may work only if your classes are located directly in file system. If however they are packed into jar the line `new FileInputStream(new File(path))` will throw `FileNotFoundException` because file indeed does not exist in file system but packed into jar.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what problem i faced and how InputStream fixed this for me, then you can decide which one to use.

I used getResource("").getFile() and it works why running on my IDEA, because it has access to create files in the background. When i extracted the Server as a Jar and executed it from cmd, it did not work, because inside the resources from Jar it does not have access to create anything.

Conclusion:
InputStream do not need for system access
File need to have access to the system

Answer (score -1):

Using an InputStream has a higher memory footprint than using a File